# Fix scale botttom colour on 0 in altair

Tags: python, pandas, altair, vega

I am generating  a waffle plot (github-like activity heatmap) in the following way:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# Import data
df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/AzwJ0va4")

# Year interactive dropdown
years = list(df["year"].unique())
year_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=years)
selection = alt.selection_single(
    fields=["year"], bind=year_dropdown, name="Year", init={"year": 2020}
)

# Plot
(
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_rect()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("week:O", title="Week"),
        y=alt.Y("day(committed_on):O", title=""),
        color=alt.Color(
            "hash:Q", scale=alt.Scale(range=["transparent", "green"]), title="Commits"
        ),
        tooltip=[
            alt.Tooltip("committed_on", title="Date"),
            alt.Tooltip("day(committed_on)", title="Day"),
            alt.Tooltip("hash", title="Commits"),
        ],
    )
    .add_selection(selection)
    .transform_filter(selection)
    .properties(width=1000, height=200)
)
```

The resulting plot is behaving 99% as I would expect, but when I select a year with no activity (`hash` column populated as 0), as **2017**, the plot will be filled with green squares as 0 anchored exactly in the middle of the scale.

How can I make sure that 0 is always placed at the bottom of the scale? (transparent color)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `domain` of the color scale the same way you set it for an axes: `scale=alt.Scale(range=["transparent", "green"], domain=[0, 16])`. It is possible to set just `domainMin` in newer version of VegaLite but not yet in Altair. In your case it is probably a got idea to set both min and max anyways, so that colors are interpreted the same for all years.

Comment: I think this is definitely a step in the right direction but I am looking to have a higher bound in `domain` that updates dynamically with the selector. 100 commits a day might be a lot for a given year and not in another (hence most years will be mostly closer to white and hard to read). No idea if there's a way to access `selection` value and dyanmically find the max vlaue each time the plot is rendered. Anyway thanks for jotting down a response

Comment: @anddt I don't think that is possible until Altair is updated to include the `domainMin` parameter for scales.